# limit exists or not?

Tags: real-analysis

If there exists limit, then what is it?

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \sqrt{\sin(\frac{x}{n})+cos(\frac{x}{n})} dx$$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The integrand is bounded by $\sqrt{2}$ hence we may take the limit inside the integral and see that this reduces to

$$\int_0^{\pi/2}\sqrt{0 + 1}\,dx ={\pi\over 2}$$

because this holds independent of $x\in [0,\pi/2]$.

Comment: nice and simple (+1)